# Does Xcode generate Assembly code for a Swift File?

Tags: swift, xcode, assembly

In fact, I am aware of that running:

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -O -emit-assembly SwiftFile.swift -o result
```

on terminal should generate "result" file which contains assembly code for "SwiftFile.swift" file.

Also, there are tools such as [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) to do such a task, furthermore, it can generate Pseudo-code to let it more easy to read.

However, is there a way to do it directly from Xcode? if there is, how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Go to your targets, click Build Phases. Add a Run Script by clicking the plus in the upper left corner. In text area add the code

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -O -emit-assembly Folder/SwiftFile.swift -o result.asm
```

This will generate an assembly file every time you build for that target. You can also create a new target if you don't want it to generate assembly every time.